# Allowing selective script loading in iframes using the 'sandbox' attribute

Tags: javascript, html

I was reading about Iframe and it looks like there is an attribute called sandbox that can prevent all the scripts from loading, however, I want to allow all the scripts except one, so is that possible?

In other words, My question is how can I allow all scripts to load in an iframe except for one using the 'sandbox' attribute? If not possible, what are alternative solutions to prevent the loading of specific scripts when using an iframe? Are there any alternatives to using iframes altogether?